# When can I change Careers?

Tags: character-advancement, wfrp-2e

Note that I'm only asking about using 100 xp to take a listed Career Exit, not using 200 xp to change to a Basic Career.

The rules on changing careers are really confusing, and it's hard to tell exactly when a character can or can't change careers. From "Your First Career":

> Eventually you will have bought every advance available within your
>   first career. When this happens, it is time to change careers.

That suggests, but doesn't actually state, that you can only change careers when you've bought all the advances available from your current career. Is that the case? If so, is there a stronger statement to be found?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The WFRP2 core rulebook is a little ambiguous on this point, depending on whether you want to go by a literal reading or to read the text in a more natural manner.

## Literal Reading

According to "Changing Careers" on p.28,

> Every career  description has a   list    of  Career  Exits... The    first   step    towards changing career is  to  pick    which   one of  these   exit    options you’d like  to  take.
>
> Before    you can enter   the new career  you’ve  chosen  there   are two
>   things     you    must    do. First,  you must    collect all the trappings   of  the
>   career    you 
>   wish  to  join.   Second, you must    pay 100 xp  to  enter   the chosen career.

There are "two things you must do" to change career, neither of which is "buy all the advances available from your current career."  You can take a career exit at any time, provided you have the requisite trappings and 100XP to spend.

Additionally, the "Career Exit Options" sidebar on p.29 states that, when changing careers, you can use the career exits from any of your previous careers, without specifying that you must have completed the career whose exit you're using.

Note that, while WFRP2 can be read ambiguously, WFRP1 explicitly stated:

> Characters may normally change careers at any time, provided they have the 100EP to do so.  In some cases, however, it is necessary for characters to have taken every advance and skill available from one career in order to progress to another.  For example, wizards' apprentices must complete their advance scheme before becoming a wizard.

## Natural Reading

In addition to the sentence cited in the question, p.30 says

> **Career Exits**
>
> When  you finish  this    career, you can take    any of  these   exits   for 100 xp.

In common usage, this phrasing implies that you cannot take those exits prior to finishing the career, just as "when you finish dinner, you can have ice cream" implicitly makes finishing dinner a prerequisite for having ice cream.

Answer (score 3):

While the rules are really bad in that point, there is a mention in  'Skill and Talent options' under 'your second career' in chapter 3. (I have a german book so the point might be slightly different named)

> Viele Karrieren stellen Fertigkeiten und Talente zur Wahl [...] Zunächst müssen sie eines von beiden kaufen, sonst können sie die Karriere nicht abschließen. Doch ehe sie Ihr Karriereschema vollenden können sie EP einsetzen um diese Optionalen Fertigkeiten und Talente zu erwerben.
>
> Many Careers offer a choice for skills and talents. [...] You need to buy one of those before you can finish a career. Before completing your current Career Schema you can buy the alternative options.

This supports, that you have to buy all upgrade options before advancing. Also don't forget, that you need to own the Base Equipment for your next class.

Comment: Also in the same part:
  “
Some careers give you options like “any two” or “any three” for skills
and talents. If you already have enough skills and talents from the list,
you don’t need to buy new ones to finish the career, but you can at your
option.
“  
This heavily implies you need to buy the skills to advance.

Answer (score 3):

Page 29 contains a sidebar "Career Exit Options" which reads:

> [...] Switching to a Basic Career that isn't one of your listed Career Exits cost 200 xp instead of 100 xp. However, you may make this switch without completing your current career [...]

This, with respect to "Career Exits" clause on page 30:

> When you finish this career, you can take any of this exits for 100 xp

implies that you have to complete your career to use 100 xp option, but do not have to do it to use 200 xp option.

Different approvements of it are scattered through the book, allready mentioned by Fourpaws and you.

Note, "Changing Careers" is right after the text you quoted, so it may be taken for granted, that "things you must do" are in addition to that quoted part, and not a self sufficient statement.

Answer (score 2):

## Up to your GM.

As [Dave said](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96833/22285), the rulebook is quite ambiguous on this point, and depending on how you read it and what is your interpretation, it can be either once you bought every advance or whenever you want, if you at least got every trapping for your next career.

My opinion is to talk with your GM and ask him what would be the solution he would be the most comfortable with, as even if there was a straight answer, the GM would be allowed to change it if he - and his players of course - would prefer to.

In my case, with WFRP, I prefer to ask my players to find a correct way to change they career in the campaign, by getting it through game and roleplay. For instance, a soldier who would like to move to a sergeant career needs to get a military advancement. He can do it by different ways, distinguishing himself in battle, through heroic acts, strategy knowledge demonstrations, or just bribing a greedy captain. Whatever the way, I will allow you to move on to his wanted career if I estimate his character owned it, ever if he didn't got all his advances. That tends to go on the opposite of what the rulebook says.

However, I am conscious it is my choice, because I and my players prefer to play that way. So ask your GM and find what works the best for your group.